# TelegramBots Java API - Get Chat object from CallbackQuery getChatInstance method

Tags: java, callback, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot

Is there a way to retrieve the chat id from a CallbackQuery object?

In my case, I have made a InlineKeyboardButton and set a callbackQueryData.
I'm able to retrieve this callback query but without chance to retrieve the chat id. I know the answerInlineQuery method but I dont need in my case. I need only a way to retrieve the chat id.

CallbackQuery class provide the getChatInstance() method but return always null.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOUND**

```
CallbackQuery callbackQuery;
Long chatId = callbackQuery.getMessage().getChatId();
```